# Using grep to find dynamic text

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, grep

Need help with a bash script. We are modifying our database structure, the problem is we have many live sites that have pre-written queries referencing the current database structure. I need to find all of our scripts with references to MySQL tables. Here is what I started:

```
grep -ir 'from' /var/www/sites/inspection.certifymyshop.com/ > resultsList.txt
```

I am trying to grep through our scripts recursively and export ALL table names found to a text file, we can use the "->from" and the "->join" prefixes to help us:

```
->from('databaseName.table_name dtn')  // dtn = table alias
```

OR

```
->join('databaseName.table_name dtn')  // dtn = table alias
```

I need to find the database and table name within the single quotes (i.e. databaseName.table_name). I also need to list the filename this was found in underneath or next to the match like so:

> someDatabaseName.someTableName  |  /var/www/sites/blah.com/index.php 
>   |  line 36

Comment: Just to make it clearer: you want to retrieve all the `databaseName.table_name dtn` from lines like `->from('databaseName.table_name dtn')  // dtn = table alias`, and list them like `databaseName.table_name dtn | source_file | line_number`, right?

Comment: anything within those quotes will be dynamic, and the "// dtn = table alias" is just a comment I made for your information, that is not within the code. So it will be ->from('databaseName.table_name dtn') and the list them like you mentioned.

Comment: I guess I'd do something very close to what @sputnick have pointed in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one problem you have with only using grep is removing the from, join or whatever identifying prefix from the result.  To fix this we can also use sed

```
grep -EHroi -- '->(from|join)\('\''[^'\'' ]*' /path/to/files | sed -re 's/:.*(from|join)\('\''/:/g'
```

You could also use sed alone in a for loop

```
for i in `find /path/to/files -type f -print`
do
   echo $i
   sed -nre 's/^.*->(from|join)\('\''([^'\'' ]*)['\'' ].*$/\2/gp' $i
done
```

Edit: The above for loop breaks with filenames with spaces so here's the previous sed statement using find

```
find ./ -type f -exec sh -c "echo {} ; sed -nre 's/^.*->(from|join)\('\''([^'\'' ]*)['\'' ].*$/\2/gp' \"{}\" ;" \;
```

Comment: @sputnick i've edited the post with a find statement that works with spaces in the filenames.

Comment: the first suggestion you typed, with grep and sed fails. -E is an invalid option, I'm on CentOS. I removed the -E and left the -e and now I get: sed: -e expression #1, char 23: Unmatched ( or \(

Comment: @user2019528 looks like it's -r for sed on centos instead of -E.  It's for extended regexp.  -E is for sed on mac osx

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
grep -oPriHn -- "->(?:from|join)\('\K[^']+" . |
    awk -F'[ :]' '{print $3, "|", $1, "| line " $2}'
```

If this fits your needs, I can explain the snippet more as well.

Comment: Hi Sputnick, this did not work, doesn't find either the from nor join. I am running CentOS.